# EJB3 Transaction REQUIRES_NEW not committed

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jta

I'm having some troubles with EJB3/JTA transaction and transaction isolation.

I'm using WildFly 17.

I have a stateless EJB method that call different method from another EJB.

I was hopping that using REQUIRES_NEW each method will have it's own transaction, and each method will make a commit to the database.

So the next method can see and use data from the database inserted or updated before.

But it's not like this. in test3() i can't see/use data from test1() and test2().

I've read many other questions and answer about this behavior, but none helped me to find a solution to this problem.

Here is a pseudo code of my problem.

```
@Stateless
public class A {
    @Inject IAnotherEJB service;

    public test() {
        service.test1();
        //here, in the "main method" i can see X from the database
        service.test2();
        //here, in the "main method" i can see X and Z from the database
        service.test3();
    }
}


@Stateless
public class AnotherEJB implements IAnotherEJB {
    
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public test1() {
        ... 
        //add X and update Y to the database (JPA)
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public test2() {
        ...
        //add/update other some data Z to the database (JPA)
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public test3() {
        ... 
        //find X and Z from the database (JPA finById)
        //Here i can't see X or Z in the database or i have some error : Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) about Y
        ... 
        //add/update other some data W to the database (JPA) using X and Z
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong using REQUIRES_NEW like this ?

Comment: It's weird. As test1 and test2 are different transactions committed before the transaction for test3 is started, in test3 you should see the changes made in test1 and test2. Try to add transaction attribute `NOT_SUPPORTED`  to method test in the `A` EJB, to see if the transaction started by default for the container (as the default attribute is `REQUIRED`) is messing with the other transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I add `NOT_SUPPORTED` to the method `test` in `A` EJB, I've got another exception : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction associated with the current thread` and it stop immediately.

Comment: Something is messing with the expected behaviour of the transactions. Are there any other EJB methods involved? Is JPA configured with a JTA datasource in `persistence.xml` ?

Comment: I've found my problem thanks to your first comment. My application is multi tenant and for some other reasons the transaction of test1() have lost the tenant while others transaction work on the good tenant. So all the transaction were not working for on the same database schema. Thank you anyway, without your suggestion i would not have point to the wrong part of my code.